# Git revert. Automatically merged files not being reset

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert

Our team is relatively new to using Git.

We've got a dev branch and and active release branch which has been in existence for a number of weeks now. So, the dev branch is well ahead of the release branch.

When fixing a particular bug, the developer created a new bug-fix branch. The problem is that he branched from the develop branch instead of the release branch.

The fix was made in a single file, but when the bug-fix branch was merged with the release branch, it also merged the other files that had recently changed in the dev branch.

How do we get to a point where the release branch is as it was before this merge?

I've tried `git revert <commit-id>` and that reverts the change in the single file that was changed in the bug-fix branch, but the other changes that made their way from the dev branch are still present.

The fact that some files were not reverted makes this question different to the others I've come across on SO.

[Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylAXg.png) shows how multiple files were updated/created/removed when I ran `git pull`.

Comment: Is the merge public (i.e. "pushed") or just on your local repository?

Comment: Here is a very good "Choose your own adventure" style guide that can help you undo things: https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html

Comment: @jchook The merge has been pushed to the remote repository. I don't have the branch the change was made on in my own local repository.

Thanks, I'll take a look at your link.

Looking at git log, I'm not sure I have the full picture of how this came about.

Will update the question  when I get more info.

Comment: @dimwittedanimal I don't think the questions are the same since I can revert the change, but other files that were inadvertently changed are not reverted.

Comment: After you sort out reverting the merge, the proper way to apply the fix on a different branch is usually to use `git cherry-pick <commit you want to copy>`.

Comment: I think the proper way to fix this would be to fully revert the commit, then rebase the feature branch off the target branch (e.g. `git checkout 33-my-feature; git rebase release`).